# What does "I put the X in XYZ" mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, word-play

I've recently faced the expression "to put X in XYZ" in a post (which I think was promoting a product). And I found out this is kind of a popular expression in some memes and also there is a [thread](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-funny-examples-of-I-put-the-X-in-XYZ?share=1) in which lots of them are provided by the commenters.
For example:

> I put the fun in funeral
>
> Microsoft: You put the "excel" in "excellent"

But I don't get what's the meaning behind it. Is it just playing for fun with a pair of words which the latter contains the first one but the meanings are far apart?

Comment: This is common in crappy local advertising. You might hear it from used car salesmen or discount furniture companies.

Comment: OP provides a link to many such examples

Comment: Thank you all for your explanations. I think I've got it. Also,  I edited my question because it wasn't actually an ad, it was a promoting Instagram post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most often a joke. There's [a discussion about that form of joke on Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3465) that explains some of the nuances:

> Here’s the thing about jokes of the form “you put the X in Y,” where X represents one or more syllables in Y: the humor only works if the X makes up a part of Y even though the two words are not related semantically. For instance, if your significant other had travelled into orbit as part of the U.S. space program, it would be funny if, after admiring their attractive backside, you said, “Baby, you put the ‘ass’ in ‘astronaut.’” However, if you were dating an Olympic champion, you shouldn’t say, “Baby, you put the ‘win’ in ‘winner,’” as that would sound very, very stupid.

It can also be used as a marketing "[tag line](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/tagline)" to associate a business with two things in a memorable way, for example "We Put the HAPPY in happy hour!". It can also be used to make someone want to find out what the tag line means exactly. For example, "We put the no in innovation", "We put the inn in innovation" or "We put the ovation in innovation". None of those combinations express an idea clearly. They are meant to tempt readers to read more to understand what relationship "no", "inn" or "ovation" has to "innovation". They are often designed to be memorable, so if a reader resists the temptation the first time they see it, by the third or fourth time they will want to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

As extensively mentioned in comments this is intended as humour or as a way of making the utterance memorable.  The most common use is as you state a phrase where someone is alleged to have put the X in XYZ. Variants may be intended more as a way of making a memorable point. For instance consider the popular phrase "There is no I in team" which is commonly used by people promoting team-working. People of a certain age also have fun with this when they find a name which contains within it a taboo word.

Comment: Just FYI, I finally got around to writing the answer and I've removed my comments since they were redundant.

Comment: @ColleenV apologies for camping on your turf. The post seemed to be languishing unanswered and I assumed Real Life had intervened and you had not the time to answer.

Comment: No apology necessary- I just wanted you to know the comments had been removed because it might affect how you wanted to word your answer. I think it would be ideal if every question had at least two answers.